# Slow JDBC connection when using MySQL in Boot2Docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am trying to use Boot2Docker (on Windows) with a standard MySQL image to use this as development database server. On my local machine i can succesfully connect to the MySQL server running inside the container, but when i try to execute some JDBC calls from my host machine it is very slow! It takes 20 to 30 seconds to return from a call.

I forwarded port 3306 to the docker-vm and checked some network settings but i am still unable to identifiy what is causing slow network / jdbc connection.

Any hints on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by setting the java.security.egd to a the value file://dev/urandom. My problem was caused by the blocking of the /dev/random device in docker.